# Rust - How to reference T value inside Option<T>

Tags: pointers, rust, reference

```rust
fn main() {
    let float = 1.0;

    let var: &f64 =  {
        let inner_option = Some(float);

        inner_option.as_ref().unwrap()
    };

    dbg!(var);
}
```

You get this error

```
error[E0597]: `inner_option` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
4 |     let var: &f64 =  {
  |         --- borrow later stored here
...
7 |         inner_option.as_ref().unwrap()
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
8 |     };
  |     - `inner_option` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How do I get a reference to the longer living `float` variable while accessing it from the Option `inner_option`?

Comment: `let var = non_copy.rect.as_ref().unwrap();`, maybe?

Comment: Your current code compiles fine. You have a lot of revisions and I don't know which one to roll back to, so do it yourself.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I accidentally put the answer code into the question. I reverted it back to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Some(float)` will *copy* the `float` making a `Option<f64>` which will be destroyed at the end of that scope, and would leave the reference invalid.

If you were to instead make an `Option<&f64>` that only *references* `float`, then it would work:

```
fn main() {
    let float = 1.0;

    let var: &f64 =  {
        let inner_option = Some(&float);

        inner_option.unwrap()
    };

    dbg!(var);
}
```